# Converting datetime format to text format in excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I have an excel file which has data like "04 17" (right aligned) but the format is showing as DateTime i.e 4/1/2017.

My C# Production code is written in such a way that it recognizes if that is mentioned as text format (left aligned).

In the below screenshot all data in "Project Start Date" column need to be left aligned (like I manually wrote in 3rd line).

I am new to excel & macro, please give some clue how to convert these values. I have around 6000 lines, so cant re enter all the columns manually.

[image]

Comment: So you c# code is reading the sheet? (not generating it) and do you want to do this as a one off fix? or is this something you want to write a program to do?

Comment: Yes, C# code is just reading it & I am trying to provide a fix without any code change as that's already in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "Custom" format on column S, enter "MM YY" in the 'Type' slot (without the quotes) ... then set left alignment for the whole column from the menu.

If you need the text version, enter this formula in an adjacent column, let's say column T, row 6: 
=TEXT(S6,"MM YY")

Extend the formula in the column to fill the 6000 row range.  You can optionally lock in the text values by copying the column and then doing a 'Paste Special - Values' into a new column.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked with "mm yy" format which I was missing when I tried initially.